# how to rewrite a hardware linux driver for android use

Tags: android, linux, driver

recently, i am doing a school project on a beagleboard which has android 2.2 ported.the beagleboard is [like this](http://www.chipsee.com/beagleboard-xm-exp-v2.html).

I have to connect a sensor called phidgets 1056 to the board.

However, the drivers provider only got linux driver for the board.
the linux driver is [available here](http://www.phidgets.com/drivers.php).

Is it possible to rewrite the source code in the linux driver so that android can use them???

If it is, how can i make it ?

I really need help now, so thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS is just another version of Linux.  If the drivers are flexible enough all you would have to do is include them in the Android libs.  For custom Android libs [check this out](http://www.uplinq.com/sites/default/files/images/Snapdragon-Lab-Creating-Custom-Drivers.pdf)  If they aren't flexible enough you will have to at the least compile the source code if you have access to it then deploy it on the Android OS.

Try this site [Custom KO](http://android-jotting.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-compile-android-device-driver-as.html) and to create an [Android image..](http://jogglerwiki.info/index.php?title=Build_Android_Image)